# multiply in javascript can't get correct answer

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why 81.66 * 15 = 1224.8999999 in Javascript (or Perl) and not 1224.9 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387675/why-81-66-15-1224-8999999-in-javascript-or-perl-and-not-1224-9)
>   [Is JavaScript’s math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

```
var t1 = 5000;
var t2 = 0.07;
alert(t1 * t2);
```

Here is very simple code that return incorrect result;
I predict the result is `350`

but the result is `350.00000000000005`

How can I get correct result?

and what's wrong in this code?

Comment: [Read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). This is a duplicate of a million other questions.

Comment: This is a duplicate of any one of the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387675/why-81-66-15-1224-8999999-in-javascript-or-perl-and-not-1224-9 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284873/float-inaccuracies-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379934/unexpected-result-using-posix-ceil-in-perl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872544/precision-of-floating-point

Comment: Indeed... A well-worn classic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken

Answer (score 3):

Floating point arithmetic in computers is an approximation of the value.

see
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Problems_with_floating-point

Comment: I disagree - it's no more a problem with floating point than 1/3 or &pi; are for the decimal number system.  You simply can't represent 0.1 exactly in binary.

Comment: @duffmo Floating point variables have a given number of bits to encode a numeric value. There are uncountably infinitely many numbers yet only a finite number of bits. Therefore, there will always be some values that cannot be represented whether you use binary or BCD or whatever using the finite number of bits available to you. Now, if you go the arbitrary precision route, you are still limited by the machine's memory which is finite. Now, keep in mind that `1/3` is the most accurate representation of `1/3`.

Comment: No, I understand it quite well, thanks.  I know all about floating point numbers.

Comment: @duffymo Are you saying that 0.1 when represented as a float is an approximation of the value 0.1? Sure sounds like you agree with Jonathan if you ignore the "I disagree" part of your comment.

Comment: What duffymo is trying to say is that every number system, regardless of base, will have trouble representing some values using a finite number of digits.

This becomes a problem with floating-point because of the *finite* number of bits available for storage according to the spec, as others have pointed out.

Comment: I'm saying that if you try to write the value 0.1 in binary that you won't be able to do it exactly: "Some numbers (e.g., 1/3 and 0.1) cannot be represented exactly in binary floating-point no matter what the precision."

Comment: There's no such thing as an exact decimal representation of 1/3, regardless.  They're called irrational numbers.  Same for pi and e.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.round()` will help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

**The** definitive article to read is

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)